# Duvida com regra IBM DB2

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, db2, ibm

Pessoal eu estou com uma dificuldade para transcrever essa estrutura de sql server para IMB DB2. Alguém poderia me ajudar.

```
with cte as
(
select 
CASE
WHEN CONVERT(datetime, format( getdate(), 'HH:MM') )  BETWEEN '06:00' AND '11:59' then 1
WHEN CONVERT(datetime, format( getdate(), 'HH:MM') )  BETWEEN '12:00' AND '16:59' then 2
WHEN CONVERT(datetime, format( getdate(), 'HH:MM') )  BETWEEN '17:00' AND '23:59' then 3
WHEN CONVERT(datetime, format( getdate(), 'HH:MM') )  BETWEEN '00:00' AND '05:59' then 4
END AS regra_job
)
select * from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Como eu faria para adicionar os minutos juntos com a hora    para o banco ibm db2. O código abaixo está em em SQL SERVER.

`select *
    from vendas v
    where convert(date, DATAVENDA) = convert(date, getdate()) 
    and 
 CASE
    WHEN format( GETDATE(), 'HH:MM' ) BETWEEN '06:00' AND '11:59' then 1
    WHEN format( GETDATE(), 'HH:MM' ) BETWEEN '12:00' AND '16:59' then 2
    WHEN format( GETDATE(), 'HH:MM' ) BETWEEN '17:00' AND '23:59' then 3
    WHEN format( GETDATE(), 'HH:MM' ) BETWEEN '00:00' AND '05:59' then 4
END = 
CASE
  WHEN CONVERT(datetime, format( DATAVENDA, 'HH:MM') )  BETWEEN '06:00' AND '11:59' then 1
  WHEN CONVERT(datetime, format( DATAVENDA, 'HH:MM') )  BETWEEN '12:00' AND '16:59' then 2
  WHEN CONVERT(datetime, format( DATAVENDA, 'HH:MM') )  BETWEEN '17:00' AND '23:59' then 3
  WHEN CONVERT(datetime, format( DATAVENDA, 'HH:MM') )  BETWEEN '00:00' AND '05:59' then 4
END`

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui uma solução para o PostgreSQL com um amigo , mas gostaria de encontrar para ibm db2

`select n.* from schema.tabela n
where 
cast( (cast( n.datavenda as TIMESTAMP with time zone)) as date) = cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) 
and 
CASE
WHEN cast( to_char( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'HH24:MM' ) as time) BETWEEN cast('06:00' as time) AND cast('11:59' as time) then 1
WHEN cast( to_char( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'HH24:MM' ) as time) BETWEEN cast('12:00' as time) AND cast('16:59' as time) then 2
WHEN cast( to_char( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'HH24:MM' ) as time) BETWEEN cast('17:00' as time) AND cast('23:59' as time) then 3
WHEN cast( to_char( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'HH24:MM' ) as time) BETWEEN cast('00:00' as time) AND cast('05:59' as time) then 4
END = 
CASE
WHEN cast( to_char((cast( n.datavenda as TIMESTAMP with time zone)), 'HH24:MM' ) as time)  BETWEEN cast('06:00' as time) AND cast('11:59' as time) then 1
WHEN cast( to_char((cast( n.datavenda as TIMESTAMP with time zone)), 'HH24:MM' ) as time)  BETWEEN cast('12:00' as time) AND cast('16:59' as time) then 2
WHEN cast( to_char((cast( n.datavenda as TIMESTAMP with time zone)), 'HH24:MM' ) as time)  BETWEEN cast('17:00' as time) AND cast('23:59' as time) then 3
WHEN cast( to_char((cast( n.datavenda as TIMESTAMP with time zone)), 'HH24:MM' ) as time)  BETWEEN cast('00:00' as time) AND cast('05:59' as time) then 4
END`

Comment: Poderia simplificar para `EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN 6 AND 11` e assim por diante.

Comment: Eu gostaria de saber se alguém tem alguma função pronta dessa para ibm db2

Comment: Tente `EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CURRENT TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN 6 AND 11`. Consulte o manual.

Comment: Irei tentar e te falo.

Answer (score -1):

Esta sería una forma de obtener el mismo resultado.

```
with cte(regra_job) as
(values
    CASE
    WHEN HOUR(CURRENT_TIME) < 6 then 4
    WHEN HOUR(CURRENT_TIME) < 12 then 1
    WHEN HOUR(CURRENT_TIME) < 17 then 2
         ELSE 3
    END
)
select * from cte
```

Comment: Obrigado Paul pela reposta.